# can i use ckeditor full fledged in c#.net

Tags: asp.net, comparison, version, ckeditor

**on ckeditor download website:**
ASP.NET Control to easily integrate CKEditor on ASP.NET pages CKEditor.NET 3.6.4. 
That means Can I use CKEditor` completely in asp.net  without using javascript or jQuery?

If it is not possible,
What is the different between CKEditor 3.6.4 vs CKEditor 3.6.5?
Any tool is available like that

Comment: CKEditor is based on JavaScript. You will not be able to use it without JS

Comment: please see my edited post for unlock my account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ckeditor is a client side editor, that works with javascript, is written on javascript.

The code behind is only used for save the content of the editor back to the database.

So the editor is only work with javascript.

Comment: please see my edited post for unlock my account

Comment: @Rameshathish Is not depend from me that because you have get many -1 and its not from me. To unlock your account you need to give some good answers and get +1 elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

No you can not use it without javascript.

```
  <CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" runat="server">
  </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

Check out this link:- http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor.NET_released

Comment: no. no. am asking without javascript or jquery support )that meens some option not able to access on asp.net only possible with js or jquerry)

Comment: Without javascript it is not possible to use CKEditor as pointed by "Pekka", the basis of CKEditor is javascript :)

Comment: please see my edited post for unlock my account